# How to send an email with libcurl in C++

Tags: c++, curl

I'm trying to send an email from C++ using libcurl 7.42.1.

I have tried their example program (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-mail.html), it builds, runs, but doesn't work.

I tried using the command line curl to do the same but it exhibits the exact same behavior as libcurl from c++ (see below).
It hangs for a while then quits with en error ("*response reading failed*").

**I've used wireshark to analyze the packet exchange and I can see that once the TCP connection is established (SYN,SYN-ACK,ACK) my endpoint doesn't send any more packets (it should start an SMTP conversation).**

What am I doing wrong?

This is the command i used:

```
curl --url "smtp://smtp.mail.yahoo.com:465" --mail-from "test-curl" --mail-rcpt "bog2k3@gmail.com" --user "*****@yahoo.com:*****" --upload-file test.txt --verbose
```

Comment: I just figured out that using port 465 was part of the problem. That port is for SMTP over SSL and I was trying to use plain text SMTP. I switched to port 25 and now my endpoint is finally having a conversation with the server.

Comment: The question is missing your C++ code. Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. *"doesn't work"* is not a good problem description. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jww, I said I used the example program (which I linked) and then I said the command line exhibits the exact same problem which I then described in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SMTP the first message sent is coming from the server, telling the client that it is ready. However, you use port 465. So I suspect the actual protocol used by the server is SMTPS, which is basically SMPT over a layer of TLS and in TLS it is the client initiating the communication. That means both server and client wait for the other side to start talking until one side times out.

The fix should simple, just specify the smtps protocol:

```
curl --url "smtps://smtp.mail.yahoo.com:465" --mail-from "test-curl" --mail-rcpt "bog2k3@gmail.com" --user "*****@yahoo.com:*****" --upload-file test.txt --verbose
```

And the corresponding example program would be here:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-ssl.html

I don't really recommend just using SMTP on port 25, as it is not encrypted.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happened. I switched to SMTPS without specifying the port manually and it works all right now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the port i used (465) which is the port for SMTP/SSL, not for plain text SMTP.
Switched to port 25 and it doesn't hang any more.